# Hardhat is not generating private keys when I run `npx hardhat node`

Tags: blockchain, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I don't know what is the problem here. When I run `npx hardhat node` I am getting only public keys.
[image]

And this is my hardhat.config.ts configuration:

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";

import "./tasks/accounts";
import "./tasks/deploy";

import { resolve } from "path";

import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import { NetworkUserConfig } from "hardhat/types";

dotenvConfig({ path: resolve(__dirname, "./.env") });

const chainIds = {
  goerli: 5,
  hardhat: 31337,
  kovan: 42,
  mainnet: 1,
  rinkeby: 4,
  ropsten: 3,
};

// Ensure that we have all the environment variables we need.
const mnemonic: string | undefined = process.env.MNEMONIC;
if (!mnemonic) {
  throw new Error("Please set your MNEMONIC in a .env file");
}

const infuraApiKey: string | undefined = process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;
if (!infuraApiKey) {
  throw new Error("Please set your INFURA_API_KEY in a .env file");
}

function getChainConfig(network: keyof typeof chainIds): NetworkUserConfig {
  const url: string = "https://" + network + ".infura.io/v3/" + infuraApiKey;
  return {
    accounts: {
      count: 10,
      mnemonic,
      path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
    },
    chainId: chainIds[network],
    url,
  };
}

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  gasReporter: {
    currency: "USD",
    enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS ? true : false,
    excludeContracts: [],
    src: "./contracts",
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      accounts: {
        mnemonic,
      },
      chainId: chainIds.hardhat,
    },
    goerli: getChainConfig("goerli"),
    kovan: getChainConfig("kovan"),
    rinkeby: getChainConfig("rinkeby"),
    ropsten: getChainConfig("ropsten"),
  },
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./artifacts",
    cache: "./cache",
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.10",
    settings: {
      metadata: {
        // Not including the metadata hash
        // https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template/issues/31
        bytecodeHash: "none",
      },
      // Disable the optimizer when debugging
      // https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/#solidity-optimizer-support
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 800,
      },
    },
  },
  typechain: {
    outDir: "typechain",
    target: "ethers-v5",
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: If you scroll down dont you see the private keys? sometimes prints all public keys first and then their respective private key

Comment: No, there is no scroll at all.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this question in the [Hardhat Discord server](https://hardhat.org/discord).

Answer (score 2):

I think you included mnemonic in your hardhat network config as shown below. Remove mnemonic and it will work

```
hardhat: {
      // accounts: {
      //   mnemonic,
      // },
      chainId: chainIds.hardhat,
    },
```